# PHPExcel_IOFactory::load xlsx формата на сервере не читает

Tags: phpexcel, yii

Здравствуйте. Подключаю PHPExcel так:

```
spl_autoload_unregister(array('YiiBase','autoload')); //Подключаем пхпексел
        Yii::import("ext.phpexcel.Classes.PHPExcel", true);
        $objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
        spl_autoload_register(array('YiiBase','autoload'));
```

Тестирую так:
xls:

```
$xls=PHPExcel_IOFactory::load(
    Yii::getPathOfAlias('webroot.protected.data').DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR."777.xls"
); //Подключаем xls файла
        $xls->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
        echo $xls->getActiveSheet()->getCellByColumnAndRow(0, 1)->getValue(); //значения первой ячейки
```

xlsx:

```
$xlsx=PHPExcel_IOFactory::load(Yii::getPathOfAlias('webroot.protected.data').DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR."777.xlsx");//Подключаем xlsx файла
        $xlsx->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
        echo '<br/>'.$xlsx->getActiveSheet()->getCellByColumnAndRow(0, 1)->getValue();//значения первой ячейки
```

На локалке всё хорошо, оба файлы читаются, а на сервере только xls читается. Никаких ошибок, просто белый экран. Инет прорыл, везде такие же примеры. Еще один момент: через библиотеки yiiexcel читается:

```
$sheet = Yii::app()->yexcel->readActiveSheet(Yii::getPathOfAlias('webroot.protected.data').DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR."777.xlsx");
print_r($sheet) //Всё ок и на сервере и на локалке
```

Только это не вариант, хочется напрямую подключится. Подскажите, какие еще есть варианты?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вообщем, так и не разобрался с последней версией пхпексел, подключил версию 1.7.8 сработал